# Ayuda con el manifest de android studio

Tags: php, java, android

Cómo logro que las dos clases MyApplication y AppController estén en el manifest?

Nota: lo que quiero incluir en el manifest no son activities en sí, sino clases que utilizo en mi App.

Éste es el contenido de mi manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dell.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ingrepto"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


       < android:name=".AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PresentacionLayout" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: ¿Tienes un Activity llamada `MyApplication` y otra llamada `AppController`?

Comment: No son activitys, son clases diferentes que utilizo para enviar datos, no se como ingresar ese app conttoller al manifest porfa

Comment: No todas las clases van en el `Manifest`, [mira lo que dice la doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html?hl=es-419): `<Activity>`: *Declara una actividad (una subclase Activity) que implementa parte de la interfaz de usuario visual de la aplicación. Todas las actividades deben estar representadas por elementos <activity> en el archivo de manifiesto. El sistema no verá las que no estén declaradas en el archivo y nunca se ejecutarán.*

Comment: Debes especificar en tu pregunta para que sea más entendible que es MyApplication y AppController , tal vez no requieras agregarlas a tu Manifest.xml....

Answer (score 2):

> Lo que quiero incluir en el manifest no son activities en sí, sino
>   clases que utilizo en mi App.

Si tus clases no extienden de las siguientes clases: `Activity`, `Service`,`BroadcastReceiver`, `ContentProvider`, no es necesario definirlas en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Los componentes de tu app que deben ser definidos en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` son:

- `<activity>` para  `Activity`.
- `<service>` para  `Service`.
- `<receiver>` para `BroadcastReceiver`.
- `<provider>` para `ContentProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

Te estabas confundiendo. Las Activity no se agregan como si fueran la aplicación misma, sino como ya tienes a `MainActivity` y a `PresentacionLayout`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ingrepto"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".PresentacionLayout" />
    <activity android:name=".MyApplication" />
    <activity android:name=".AppController"/>

</application>
```

[Aquí puedes ver](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html?hl=es-419) cómo se estructura el  archivo Manifest.

Comment: No son activitys y el manifest me da error cuando las ingreso como activitys, son apllications que no se como agregar las dos

Comment: Creo que en el Manifest sólo puedes agregar una aplicación. No sé si lo que tienes [es algo como esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19002222/5587982). Varias Clases que extienden de `Application`. Entonces tienes que jerarquizarlas como se explica en esa respuesta. El problema no se resolverá agregando varios apartados `application` en el Manifest.